# How to increase perpendicular distance of labels from arrow in XYPic?

Tags: formatting, xy-pic

How do I move a label further away from an arrow in XYPic?

Example

```
\xymatrix{
g_0 + \beta_1)(n + n') \ar[r]_-{(g_0 + \beta_1)^+(n,n')} & (g_0 + \beta_1)(n) + (g_0 + \beta_1)(n')
}
```

I want to move the label further down.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome message, I apologize for not reading the starter guide before posting.

Comment: No need to apologize; have a look at the guide at your leisure.